# GAE python explorer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

When i try to explorer my python GAE backend in local host nothing appears, and when i look into the log, this is what appears:

```
2013-09-17 20:27:03 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\Renzo\\Desktop\\engineapp']"
INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:06,841 devappserver2.py:557] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-09-17 20:27:06,858 api_server.py:327] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:32,516 module.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:41,940 module.py:593] default: "GET /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:45,551 module.py:593] default: "GET /_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.es.TB94DdVNa4o.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTONERRh8JkOutwE4dX0rKeVJfEYmg HTTP/1.1" 200 1933
ERROR    2013-09-17 23:27:45,628 wsgi.py:262] 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Renzo\Desktop\engineapp\backend.py", line 34
    entity.contrasenia=""
    ^
    IndentationError: unexpected indent

INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:45,638 module.py:593] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2013-09-17 20:27:45,638 module.py:593] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 60
```

And this is the code....

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from model_usuario import *
from protorpc import remote
from model_usuario import *

@endpoints.api(name='Usuario', version='v1', description='')
class Usuario(remote.Service):
    """Clase Usuario v1"""
    @endpoints.method(LoginRequest, LoginResponse, path='acceso', http_method='POST', name='acceso.login')

    def login(self, request):
        if(request.nombre is None):
            request.nombre=""
        Key=db.Key.from_path('Usuario', request.nombre)
        usrSearch=db.get(key)
        entity=LoginResponse()
        if(usrSearch is None):
            entity.nombre="error"
            entity.contrasenia=""
            return entity
        else:
            entity.nombre="ok"
            """entity.contrasenia="ok"""
        if(request.contrasenia==usrSerach.contrasenia):
            entity.contrasenia="ok"
        else:
            entity.contrasenia="error"
        return entity
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Your code (which you don't show us, so we can't really help) is indented wrong.

Comment: That is the code, i'm sorry.

Comment: You've mixed tabs and spaces in your code.  Switch all of the tabs to 4 spaces. If your text editor can't do this for your automatically, find one that can.

Answer (score -1):

The exception seems to state clearly what the error is:

```
File "C:\Users\Renzo\Desktop\engineapp\backend.py", line 34
  entity.contrasenia=""
  ^
  IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Indentation is significant in Python, and it seems the interpreter is seeing something wrong in your code on the indicated line.

Now, in code you've provided, that line appears to be indented as it should be, so I'm not sure we'll be able to help you other than to say: Look on line 34, and make sure your indentation is correct in your actual code! It should have exactly the same indentation as the lines above and below it.